# Is there a term for people who manage the money of dual citizens?

Tags: united-states, investing, canada, taxes, international

I'm a dual citizen of the United States and Canada. I'm afraid to invest in anything because the tax treaties and laws between the two countries make everything too complicated for me to follow.

Even the most basic investments, such as putting money into a Roth IRA (US) vs. TFSA (Canada), are too complicated because of these laws and treaties. As a result, all of my savings are just sitting in a savings account, because I'm too afraid of making a bad investment decision.

Are there any types of people who specialize in managing the savings of people such as myself? If so, is there a special term I can use to find them?

Answer (score 2):

Your first step should be meeting with a CPA or tax attorney who specializes in the taxation of dual citizens. Your local accountant can probably refer you to someone.

There are many people in that situation, and while I'm not familiar with the details, I know there are tax treaties between the U.S. and Canada designed to address your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Citizenship matter for US reporting, but not for Canadian taxes.  If you are an American resident then you need only worry about US taxes and rules.  s